# Coq: prove that if (A, B) = (C, D) then A = C /\ B = D

Tags: coq, theorem-proving

As in title, I cannot find sufficient tools to solve this trivial thing:

```
p : (A, B) = (C, D)
------------
A = C /\ B = D
```

How can I prove it?

Comment: Sometimes called: proof of equality with destructuring. Can involve pattern matching: f(g(A)) = f(g(B)) when A = B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got it. It was `pair_equal_spec`:

```
Proof.
  intros.
  apply pair_equal_spec.
  assumption.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 2):

A more primitve way to prove it is `injection p`.

It's also interesting to look at how `pair_equal_spec` itself is proved in the standard library, using the hypothesis `(a1, b1) = (a2, b2)` to rewrite `fst (a1, b1)` and `snd (a1, b1)`.

```
Lemma pair_equal_spec :
  forall (A B : Type) (a1 a2 : A) (b1 b2 : B),
    (a1, b1) = (a2, b2) <-> a1 = a2 /\ b1 = b2.
Proof with auto.
  split; intros.
  - split.
    + replace a1 with (fst (a1, b1)); replace a2 with (fst (a2, b2))...
      rewrite H...
    + replace b1 with (snd (a1, b1)); replace b2 with (snd (a2, b2))...
      rewrite H...
  - destruct H; subst...
Qed.
```